# manually calling hover does not work

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with the following code:

```
<li>
    <a href="http://example.com" id="webd">
        <span class="hot">W</span>eb Development
    </a>
</li>
..................
<p class='web' > Web for all</p>
```

CSS file :

```
.hover {
  background: #000;
}

.hot{
    text-decoration:underline;
}`
```

Javascript file :

```
 $('body').keypress(function(event){
    if(String.fromCharCode(event.which)=="w" || String.fromCharCode(event.which)=="W")
    {
        $('#webd').hover();
    }........
    .....
    }
    $('#webd').hover(function(event)
    {
      $('.web').show();
      $('.prog').hide();
      $('.rdbms').hide();
      $('#webd').addClass('hover');
    }, function()
    {
      $('#webd').removeClass('hover');
    });
```

Even though with

```
alert(String.fromCharCode(event.which))
```

I get w or W
manually calling `hover()` doesn't work. The text 'Web for all' isn't being displayed....

Can anyone explain that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's a difference between classes and pseudo-classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hover is not an event, it is a short hand for registering mouseenter and mouseleave event handlers

So trigger the mouseenter/mouseleave events

```
$('#webd').mouseenter();//or $('#webd').trigger('mouseenter');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v8QPU/)

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much!! Now I see why hover didn't work

Comment: one last thing. now the background color for the hovered element doesn't change when i leave that same element. do you know ehat's the cause of that?